# Two relationships between two same models/tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5.5

## Problem

Hello, I'm having some trouble trying to make work two relationships between the two models (Laravel 5.5): `Order` and `User`.

1-----m | A `User` (as a customer) can make many `Order`s
1-----m | A `User` (as an employee) can take many `Order`s

So, in my `orders` table I have `user_id` and `employee_id` as foreign keys.

Now, some orders doesn't have an initial `employee_id` because orders need to be accepted, then I set up that value.

Using tinker, I've located this `Order` object (id:30), it has a `user_id` and a `employee_id` but when I `dd()` it, this returns:

```
=> App\Models\Order {#882
     order_id: 30,
     user_id: 7,  // <-- foreign key
     employee_id: 6,  // <-- foreign key
     restaurant_id: 4,  // <-- foreign key (for other table)
     // ...
     total: "120.00",
     created_at: "2018-01-31 00:15:41",
     updated_at: "2018-01-31 00:15:41",
     deleted_at: null,
     restaurant: App\Models\Restaurant {#900 // <- MY RESTAURANT RELATION (M-1)
       restaurant_id: 4,
       name: "Stark, Padberg and Buckridge",
       // ...
       // ...
       created_at: "2018-01-12 18:18:17",
       updated_at: "2018-01-12 18:18:17",
       deleted_at: null,
     },
     customer: App\Models\User {#914 // <- MY CUSTOMER RELATION (M-1)
       user_id: 7,
       restaurant_id: 4,
       // ...
       created_at: "2018-01-30 17:52:33",
       updated_at: "2018-01-30 23:32:00",
       deleted_at: null,
     },
     deliverer: null,  // <-- THIS SHOULD CONTAIN THE EMPLOYEE DATA
//                            THAT BELONGS TO THE DELIVERER RELATION
     }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

### -----

Information of my logic.

## Models

#### Order

In my `Order` model I've defined the relationships (among other ones) as follows (all my primary keys follow this convention: `model_id`):

```
/**
 * Return the user who created the order.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(
        'App\Models\User',
        'user_id',
        'user_id'
    );

}

/**
 * Return the employee (user) who deliver the order.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function deliverer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(
        'App\Models\User',
        'employee_id',
        'user_id'
    );
}
```

#### User

```
/**
 * A customer can make many orders
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function ordersMade()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order',
        'user_id',
        'user_id'
    );
}

/**
 * An employee attends many orders.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function ordersDelivered()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order',
        'employee_id',
        'user_id'
    );
}
```

## Tables

This is the schema of my `orders` table:

[image: orders table]

This is the schema of my `users` table:

[image: users table]

---

## Update

Yes, I have users with ids `6` and `7`:

[image: Table]

In Tinker i've done:

```
>>> $o = App\Models\Order::find(30);
>>> $o->customer;
>>> $o->restaurant;
>>> $o->deliverer;
>>> $o;
```

Comment: Do you have a user with id 6 ?

Comment: Can you show what you're running in Tinker to get that output?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi I've updated my question to add the requested information.

Comment: @Jonathon I've updated my question to add the requested information.

Comment: @MahdiYounesi oh my god. I've forgot that I have the softDeletes activated, so the record will perdure but "logically" the object is deleted. I feel so stupid, i've been reviewing my code almost a couple of hours.

Comment: @HCK glad your problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there wasn't any problem with my code. I have the `softDeletes` set to `true` on my models, so I was trying to get a property of a "deleted" element.

As simple as that. Thanks to @MahdiYounesi, who made me check that.

although the problem was almost a stupid one, is a good remainder to note that when you need to also return `softDeleted` records when querying from an entity, you could just -as the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models) says- add `withTrashed()` in each query that needs this kind of results, or directly in the model when defining the relationship like this:

```
/**
 * Return the user who created the order.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(
        'App\Models\User',
        'user_id'
    )->withTrashed();

}

/**
 * Return the employee (user) who deliver the order.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function deliverer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(
        'App\Models\User',
        'employee_id',
        'user_id'
    )->withTrashed();
}
```

This will collect the "deleted" data, usefull for historical information for example.